# How can I align the scale on my HighCharts graph with the axis rather than the margins?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

By default, the scale for the x-axis and y-axis are on the bottom & left of the chart, respectively, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/z7eyv/60/

I want them adjacent to the plot lines (the x- and y-axis). Here's an illustration of what I'm hoping to achieve: [imgur.com/a/tf53t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ssBJ.jpg)

I know that I can use offset: to move the scales to a specific pixel location, but they no longer align to the plot lines if I change the maximum/minimum values on either axis.

I labeled where I think offset should go in the code below, but I'm not sure what to type after it.

Here's the specific part of the code in question:

```
yAxis: {
min: -20,
  max: 20,
  tickInterval: 1,
    endOnTick: false,

    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0.1,
        width: 1,
        color: 'black'}]
},
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false,
                    halo: {
                        size: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
  xAxis: {
  min: -20,
  max: 14,
  tickInterval: 1,
   gridLineWidth: 1,
    endOnTick: false,
    offset: //???????????????????????????????????????
    title: {
        text: '', 

    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0.1,
        width: 1,
        color: 'black'}]
},
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think that in your case you should be able to use zero-align-axes plugin: https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/42/Zero-align%20y-axes

Comment: Thanks for your reply & the link, @GrzegorzBlachliński. I don't think it quite addresses my issue, though. Did you see the image that I uploaded to Imgur? It shows what I'm trying to achieve: in my JsFiddle, the numbers are in the margin to the left and the bottom of my graph; I want them right next to my axes. (I don't want to change the numbers, themselves.)

Comment: Thanks for your message. It looks that I have mistakenly shown you wrong plugin - sorry for that! You can use crossing-specific-value plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/z7eyv/67/

Comment: Thanks, @GrzegorzBlachliński; that provides the crux of the solution. However, do you know if there's some way to put the numbers on the x-axis below the axis rather than above? I tried using `offset` but it didn't work. I also tried  searching online using the plugin name but couldn't find a work-around.

Comment: You should be able to use labels.y for moving your labels in y direction: http://jsfiddle.net/z7eyv/69/

Comment: Impressive - thanks so much @GrzegorzBlachliński! At the risk of annoying you, I now need to remove the 0's from both the x-axis scale and the y-axis scale because they intersect the lines near the origin and it looks messy. Is this possible?

Comment: You should be able to use labels.formatter for removing unnecessary labels. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z7eyv/71/ If this example meets your requirement I will post it as an answer

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Wow, thank you! If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept & upvote it. (Just for my own knowledge, how exactly does the function that you added to labels use ` return this.value ? this.value : ''` to remove the 0's?

Comment: I have used ternary operator for returning value if it is different than 0/undefined/null. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comments, you can use 'crossing-specific-values' plugin, available in Highcharts plugin repository:
https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values

You should be able to use labels.y option for moving your labels up/down
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.y

You should also be able to disable 0 values from your labels using labels.formatter:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter

```
  yAxis: {
    min: -20,
    max: 20,
    crossing: 0,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value ? this.value : ''
      }
    },

    tickInterval: 1,
    endOnTick: false,

    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0.1,
      width: 1,
      color: 'black'
    }]
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false,
          halo: {
            size: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    min: -20,
    max: 14,
    crossing: 0,
    opposite: true,
    visible: true,
    tickInterval: 1,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    endOnTick: false,
    labels: {
      y: 13,
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value ? this.value : ''
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: '',

    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0.1,
      width: 1,
      color: 'black'
    }]
  },
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/z7eyv/71/